# findOne returning me null even though there is entries in my DB NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

This is my User Model

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("User", {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
    return User
}
```

and i am try to find if there is any entry in my User table of given email

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email
    User.findOne({ where: { email: email } }).then((result) => {
        if (result == null) {
            console.log("data is null", result)
            res.send("No data found")
        } else {
            res.send(result)
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Error in find one")
    })
})
```

this is the the output in my terminal

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email` = 'abc@gmail.com';
data is null null
```

This is the User table in my DB .[image: This is my User table in DB]

Comment: If you run this query `SELECT LENGTH(email), LENGTH('abc@gmail.com') FROM Users;` does it return the same length?

Comment: Just copy the generated SQL and try to execute it against the DB in some DB explorer (like DBeaver)

Comment: You can begin by troubleshooting where the issue might be coming from and its most like from the req.body.email, also ensure that req.body.email always has an email address (not being null), log the entire req.body to see what it contains and log the result that was found before trying to do any operations on it. This will allow you see what data types and formats you are working with before doing anything with them